# Image upload with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Using selenium web driver with java. I have an image upload control using which i need to upload an image. I have tried .sendKeys method by passing image path that didn't work.
I have tried robot class, first clicks the button that opens a Window (windows native window) but it didn't type the keys in the "File Name" area.

[image]

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-company_logo post-fieldSet"> 
  <label for="company_logo">Opportunity image:</label> 
  <div class="field"> 
    <div class="upload-button"> 
      <button class="button">Choose File</button> 
      <span>No file chosen</span> 
      <input class="input-text" name="company_logo" id="company_logo" placeholder="" type="file"> 
    </div> 
    <small class="description"> Max. file size: 2MB. Allowed file format: jpg, gif, png </small> 
  </div> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full HTML? We need it in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is html of control

<fieldset class="fieldset-company_logo post-fieldSet">
   <label for="company_logo">Opportunity image:</label>
   <div class="field">
      <div class="upload-button">
         <button class="button">Choose File</button>
         <span>No file chosen</span>
         <input class="input-text" name="company_logo" id="company_logo" placeholder="" type="file">
      </div>
      <small class="description">
      Max. file size: 2MB. Allowed file format: jpg, gif, png
      </small>
   </div>
</fieldset>

Comment: Have you tried to use SendKeys to the div of type file not on the button itself?

Comment: I have tried every thing from fieldset to input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my question please review below details:

1. Function to set data to clip board, I will user this to set image path to clip board that I will user later on model window:

   ```
   public static void setClipboardData(String string) {

   StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);

   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

   }
   ```
2. Now review these lines of code

   ```
   WebElement upload_btn =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(choose_file_btn_xpath));

   Thread.sleep(4000);

   setClipboardData(selected_image_path);

   Actions builder  = new Actions(driver);

   Action myAction = builder.click(upload_btn).release().build();

   myAction.perform();

   Robot rbt = new Robot();
   rbt.delay(4000);
   rbt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   rbt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   rbt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   rbt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   rbt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   rbt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   rbt.delay(4000);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath(submit_button_xpath)).click();
   ```

Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: It is best practice to not use Thread.sleep.  Better to use WebDriverWait - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Thank Mike for make me aware of good practices. I have changed that. Yes, @Lucy it is working for me. Is there any improvement here for me.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you found a way for uploading image. Just to share with you another way of doing this. At instance, if in single go you need to upload all images/files (one or more) sitting in a folder, you can use this script:

```
@Test
public void Upload() throws InterruptedException
{          
File images = new File("*path where all images are saved*");
File[] eimages = images.listFiles();
String imageList = "";
for(int i = 0; i < eimages.length; i++){
    imageList += (i != 0 ?"\n":"") + eimages[i].getAbsolutePath();
}
driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload")).sendKeys(fishList);
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Images Uploaded");
}
```